# Select text and background for entire pdf document using iText java

Tags: java, file-io, itext

I'm looking to take a pdf file, set the background colour for every page to black, and all the text to white.

What's the easiest way for me to do this? Is there an api call to select every page's background and all the text in the file? Or do I have to iterate through each page somehow?

Comment: First of all, you do have to treat each page individually. Now the trouble starts, though: Nominally the backdrop of a displayed PDF is white. Thus, to have a black backdrop, you have to add a black background, e.g. by paining a black rectangle in the back. But now some PDFs put a white rectangle under each of their pages. You'll have to recognize that and remove that rectangle or change its colour. Furthermore the text may be painted using a blend mode *multiply* or *darken*. In those cases you'll have to consider changing not only the text color but also its blend mode. It is more difficult

Comment: Any chance you know how to do all of that offhand?

Comment: With itext you first of all need to use a PdfStamper for the manipulation at hand.  For the general black background you add a black rectangle to the UnderContent. The other tasks are more difficult, though.  I've got another idea, though: Theoretically it should suffice to paint a white rectangle above the page content with blend mode "difference". I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my last comment to your question, painting a white rectangle in blend mode *Difference* should do the job as long as inverting all colors is a sufficient solution for your task:

```
void invert(File source, File target) throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source.getPath());
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(target);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);
    invert(stamper);
    stamper.close();
    os.close();
}

void invert(PdfStamper stamper)
{
    for (int i = stamper.getReader().getNumberOfPages(); i>0; i--)
    {
        invertPage(stamper, i);
    }
}

void invertPage(PdfStamper stamper, int page)
{
    Rectangle rect = stamper.getReader().getPageSize(page);

    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(page);
    PdfGState gs = new PdfGState();
    gs.setBlendMode(PdfGState.BM_DIFFERENCE);
    cb.setGState(gs);
    cb.setColorFill(new GrayColor(1.0f));
    cb.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    cb.fill();

    cb = stamper.getUnderContent(page);
    cb.setColorFill(new GrayColor(1.0f));
    cb.rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    cb.fill();
}
```

`invertPage` does draw the afore mentioned white reactangle in blend mode Difference *over* the page. Furthermore it paints a white rectangle normally *under* the page; that turned out to be necessary at least for the Acrobat Reader version I have at hands here.

You might want to tweak the code somewhat to make the result better to read. Maybe the blend mode *Exclusion* (`BM_EXCLUSION`) is more appropriate, or maybe some other graphic state tweaks improve your reading experience. Just be creative! ;)

For some backgrounds on the PDF blending mode you might want to read section 11.3.5 *Blend Mode* in the [PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and study the [transparency related examples](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=241) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

PS: This code only inverts the page content. Annotations are not affected. If that turns out to be necessary, you might do something similar to their appearance streams.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution in an android application, do I need to use a particular port for itext to work with android? I'm getting a bunch of build linking problems at runtime.

Comment: I have not used itext on Android yet.  There are special ports of itext for Android, for the current itext Version a port is available on itextpdf.com. If that is required for your needs I don't know.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, though I am seeing a port called droidText hosted other places. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: that url appears to have been removed meanwhile. Simply look for iTextG, the version for GAE which has similar restrictions as Android.