# Reverse white and black colors in a PDF

Tags: pdf

Given a black and white PDF, how do I reverse the colors such that background is black and everything else is white?

Adobe Reader does it (*Preferences -> Accessibility*) for viewing purposes only in the program. But does not change the document inherently such that the colors are reversed also in other PDF readers.

How to reverse colors permanently?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the text and background color of a PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942955/changing-the-text-and-background-color-of-a-pdf-file)

Comment: If you also consider programming a solution yourself, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16877278/1729265) may help.

Answer (score 27):

You can run the following Ghostscript command:

```
gs -o inverted.pdf    \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  \
   -c "{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub}{1 exch sub} setcolortransfer" \
   -f input.pdf
```

Acrobat will show the colors inverted.

The four identical parts `{1 exch sub}` are meant for CMYK color spaces and are applied to C(yan), M(agenta), Y(ellow) and (blac)K color channels in the order of appearance.

You may use only three of them -- then it is meant for RGB color spaces and is applied to R(ed), G(reen) and B(lue).

Of course you can "invent" you own transfer functions too, instead of the simple `1 exch sub` one: for example `{0.5 mul}` will just use 50% of the original color values for each color channel.

---

**Note:** Above command will show ***ALL*** colors inverted, not just black+white!

**Caveats:**

1. Some PDF viewers won't display the inverted colors, notably *Preview.app* on Mac OS X, *Evince*, *MuPDF* and *PDF.js (Firefox PDF Viewer)* won't. But Chrome's native PDF viewer *PDFium* will do it, as well as Ghostscript and Adobe Reader.
2. It will not work with **all** PDFs (or for all pages of the PDF), because it is also dependent on how exactly the document's colors are defined.

---

### Update

Command above updated with added `-f` parameter (required) before the input.pdf. Sorry for not noticing this flaw in my command line before. I got aware of it again only because some good soul gave it its first upvote today...
**Additional update:** The most recent versions of Ghostscript do not require the added `-f` parameter any more. Verified with v9.26 (may also be true even with v9.25 or earlier versions).

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work either in OSX and iPhone default viewer "Books".

Comment: I said this already: in OSX/macOS' *Preview.app* it doesnt work. The reason is that Preview.app does only fully cover the PDF spec of PDF-1.3. Don't expect iPhone's current iOS to be any better than current macOS....

Comment: Funny thing. After using this approach I can view it in Chrome and the colors are inverted but if I print it from Chrome it prints in the original colors!

Comment: @PICyourBrain: When you print it from Chrome, things can easily go down an unexpected path again: depending on your operating system as well as on the target printer, the PDF will be converted to a different file format again (PostScript, XPS, another PDF) and then run through various filters which may or may not apply or honor the inserted transfer function, or simply not know what to do with it...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle So what you're saying is WYSINWYG!

Comment: @PICyourBrain: I think my answer made it already amply clear that there is no method to make it work reliably for all viewers. Maybe I should have added that it's again another question when *printing*, even if it works from a certain viewer?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle Yes, your answer was clear. My comment was mostly just lamenting this reality :)

Comment: @PICyourBrain: I see :-)

Comment: Works on Mac OS Catalina (10.15.6) with Acrobat DC and Foxit Reader 4.x (and Foxit PhantomPDF 4.x). I exported an Apple Keynote presentation to PDF and then inverted its colors with this. Thank you!

Comment: Finally, take your new inverted pdf from `gs` and open it with  `open -a 'google chrome' yourPdfName.pdf`

Comment: Does this do a lossless of images in the PDF?

Comment: @Geremia: This command does not change any code for the embedded images. (However, these images may be lossy already by themselves, if they are JPEG-compressed.)

Answer (score 3):

Best method would be to use "pdf2ps - Ghostscript PDF to PostScript translator", which convert the PDF to PS file.

Once PS file is created, open it with any text editor & add `{1 exch sub} settransfer` before first line.

Now "re-convert" the PS file back to PDF with same software used above.

Comment: I got an error running the script: line 2:  : command not found

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Adobe PDF printer installed, you go to Print -> Adobe PDF -> Advanced... -> Output area and select the "Invert" checkbox. Your printed PDF file will then be inverted permanently.

Answer (score 1):

None of the previously posted solutions worked for me so I wrote this simple bash script. It depends on `pdftk` and `awk`. Just copy the code into a file and make it executable. Then run it like:

```
$ /path/to/this_script.sh /path/to/mypdf.pdf
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      
pdftk "$1" output - uncompress | \                                               
awk '                                                                            
  /^1 1 1 / {                                                                    
    sub(/1 1 1 /,"0 0 0 ",$0);                                                   
    print;                                                                       
    next;                                                                        
  }                                                                              

  /^0 0 0 / {                                                                    
    sub(/0 0 0 /,"1 1 1 ",$0);                                                   
    print;                                                                       
    next;                                                                        
  }                                                                              

  { print }' | \                                                                 
pdftk - output "${1/%.pdf/_inverted.pdf}" compress
```

This script works for me but your mileage may vary.  In particular sometimes the colors are listed in the form `1.000 1.000 1.000` instead of `1 1 1`. The script can easily be modified as needed. If desired, additional color conversions could be added as well.

For me, the pdf2ps -> edit -> ps2pdf solution did not work. The intermediate .ps file is inverted correctly, but the final .pdf is the same as the original.  The final .pdf in the suggested gs solution was also the same as the original.

Comment: this does not work at all for me; in the uncompressed pdf file there are no substrings that look like 1 1 1 or 0 0 0, so the awk substitution doesn't actually do anything

Comment: @xdavidliu perhaps the colors are in decimal form such as '1.000 1.000 1.000'.

Answer (score 1):

Cross Platform try [MuPDF](https://www.mupdf.com/downloads/)

`Mutool draw -I -o out.pdf in.pdf [range of pages]`

It should permanently change colours in many viewers

[image]

### Later Edit

A sample file that did not reverse was one with linework only (no image) and the method needed was to save the graphics as inverted image  then reuse that to build a replacement PDF, however beware converting the whole pages to image will make any searchable text just simply unsearchable pixels thus would need to be run with the OCR active on rebuild.

The two commands needed will be something like (%4d means numbers for images start output0001)

```
mutool draw -o output%4d.png -I input.pdf
```

For Linux users the folowing second pass should work easily:-

```
mutool convert -O compress -o output.pdf output*.png
```

For windows users you will for now (v1.19) need to combine by scripting or use groups

```
mutool convert -O compress -o output.pdf output0001.png output0002.png output0003.png
```

next version may include an @filelist option see https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=703163

Comment: I tried this many times, to invert the colors in the hand written notes on my tab as I write using inverted colors. But, mutool always returns me the same pdf. No colors seem to change.

Comment: Here is the link: https://transfer.sh/TBD8m7/Test.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a frontend for the ghostscript command Kurt Pfeifle posted, but you could also use imagemagick with something like:

```
convert -density 300 -colorspace RGB -channel RGB -negate input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: Not lossless, though