# Overriding postscript /setcmykcolor

Tags: postscript, eps

I'm trying to change the color from EPS files that contain only vectors (no rasters). Currently, I convert them to SVG, manipulate the colors, and convert them back to PDF or EPS with Inkscape. This works perfectly but doesn't allow me to apply CMYK coloring, only RGB. After investigating a little bit and finding answers like [this](https://superuser.com/a/249038/255164) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287097/1335209) I'm trying to override the `/setcmykcolor` function my EPS file uses. You can download it from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekDvuBymVWxpjuKA7mRQeQmb1eEDki2a/view?usp=sharing).

The EPS looks like this:

[image]

And I want to convert the color to CMYK = 0 1 1 0 so it looks like this:

[image]

In this case, the EPS file is black but it could be any other color. I tried adding this after `%%BeginProlog` which should override the `/setcmykcolor` to always apply `0 1 1 0` as the CMYK color:

```
/osetcmykcolor {/setcmykcolor} bind def /setcmykcolor {pop [0 1 1 0] osetcmykcolor} def
```

Or this:

```
/osetcmykcolor {/setcmykcolor} bind def /setcmykcolor {0 1 1 0 osetcmykcolor} def
```

But everything is still black. I know `/setcmykcolor` is the right function because using `0 1 1 0 setcmykcolor` just before drawing the path makes it red. I went through postscript programming manuals but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what's wrong here!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The slash looks wrong in `{/setcmykcolor} bind def`. I think that should be written without a slash there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I start Ghostscript then do :

```
GS> /osetcmykcolor /setcmykcolor load def
GS> /setcmykcolor {pop pop pop pop 0 1 1 0 osetcmykcolor} bind def
GS> (color.eps) run
```

then the EPS is rendered in 'orange' as you expect.

Note that setcmykcolor takes 4 arguments so you have to pop all 4 (though this won't be causing a lack of colour, it's just leaving junk on the stack).

Editing the EPS file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 564 454
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.00 0.00 564.00 453.20
%%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 921 (eps2write)
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%CreationDate: D:20200616000003-03'00'
%%Pages: 1
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
/osetcmykcolor /setcmykcolor load def
/setcmykcolor {pop pop pop pop 0 1 1 0 osetcmykcolor} bind def
/DSC_OPDFREAD true def
```

and then running it with:

```
gs color1.eps
```

also produces orange text. So how are you testing it ?

Comment: Thank you so much KenS! Your code worked perfectly, as always you are postscript savior :)

Comment: Do you know of any method to do the same thing with PDFs? I mean, replacing all colors with a single color?

Comment: The short answer is 'you can't'. But that's not strictly true, there are ways, just not very good ones. With the current implementation of Ghostscript, which uses a PostScript program to render PDF files, you can achieve the same result but you have to redefine the operators before the PDF interpreter is loaded, which is during startup so you can't. What you would have to do is alter the PDF interpreter program. Its in ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_*.ps you would need to modify the use of the colour operators in that program.